# Unable to add formGroup to FormArray

Tags: angular, forms, ionic2, ionic3

I am unable to add an Angular Reactive Form group to a FormArray. See the code below.

**Home.ts**

```ts
ngOnInit(){
    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      items: this.formBuilder.array([])
    });
    this.addItemsToForm(); 

    console.log("form----- "+JSON.stringify(this.myForm.value))
  }

addItemsToForm(){
    const arrayControl = <FormArray>this.myForm.get('items')
    arrayControl.push(
      this.formBuilder.group({
        hazardStatus: ["dsad"],
      })
    )
  }
```

**Home.html**

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <div formArrayName="items">

   <div *ngFor="let model of items; let k = index;" no-padding style="background-color:transparent">
      {{items.length}}
      <div [formGroupName]="k">
          {{items.length}}
          <ion-item>
              <ion-label item-left stacked>
                  {{model.hazardStatus}}
              </ion-label>
          </ion-item>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

My Logs shows form value  `{"items":[{"hazardStatus":"dsad"}]}`

However, the form isn't showing.

Comment: What is `[formGroupName]`?

Comment: formArray contains group so given in template. Can you help me with right syntax?

Comment: I'm asking for why you're binding a number to the `[formGroupName]` attribute. You're supposed to bind it to a string. (And you don't need those square brackets to bind to the attribute)

Comment: I removed `[formGroupName]` but dint help